# ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE using @bufbuild/connect to connect to a python grpcio server

Tags: typescript, web, grpc

Im trying to connect to a [python grpc server built using grpcio](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/) from a web browser using [connect-query](https://github.com/bufbuild/connect-query). The problem im facing is that when I do a request, I get a ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE in the browser. Here is the react App component

```
// [...]
import { TransportProvider } from '@bufbuild/connect-query';
import { createConnectTransport } from '@bufbuild/connect-web';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const transport = createConnectTransport({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:50051",
    useBinaryFormat: true,
  });

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Suspense fallback='loading'>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <TransportProvider transport={transport}>
                        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                            <RouterProvider router={router} />
                        </QueryClientProvider>
                    </TransportProvider>
                </Provider>
            </Suspense>
        );
    }
}
```

The component I'm testing

```
export function MyController() {
    const { data } = useQuery(login.useQuery());
    console.log(data)

    return <MyView />;

}
```

The server in python

```py
import asyncio

import grpc
import uvloop
from grpc_reflection.v1alpha import reflection

from .status.servicer import StatusServicer, status_pb2, status_pb2_grpc


async def serve() -> None:
    server = grpc.aio.server()

    status_pb2_grpc.add_StatusServicer_to_server(StatusServicer(), server)
    
    service_names = (
        status_pb2.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name["Status"].full_name,
        reflection.SERVICE_NAME,
    )
    reflection.enable_server_reflection(service_names, server)
    
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    
    await server.start()
    await server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with asyncio.Runner(loop_factory=uvloop.new_event_loop) as runner:
        runner.run(serve())
```

So I'm missing something? It is supposed that connect-query [does not need a proxy](https://connectrpc.com/docs/faq/#how-does-connect-compare-to-grpc-web) and it should connect out-of-the-box as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the connect protocol doesn't require a proxy but the backend in this case is using the grpc protocol not connect, grpc requires a proxy to translate to connect/grpc-web. grpc-web is a different protocol built to helps proxies translate regular HTTP requests to grpc requests.

You can either:

- Use a proxy to setup the translation. Envoy is the usual choice. It can translate from connect/grpc-web to grpc. But there are [others](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#proxy-interoperability)
- Switch to a backend that supports grpc-web like: https://github.com/public/sonora (no prior experience just a quick google search)

Once you implement either of these solutions with grpc-web, the right transport to use for grpc-web is by calling `createGrpcWebTransport` instead of `createConnectTransport`.